# Can we make a Custom Tab Disappear if there is no Data in it on Account Record Page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, account, custom-tab

- I have created a Custom Tab in salesforce on Account Record Page and inside it, I have my custom LWC Components. The use case I am looking forward to is to make that tab disappear when a certain condition arises(in this case if my component returns no data). Is there any way to make a certain custom tab disappear according to these conditions?
- Any leads to how this can be achieved are welcomed here! Looking forward to hearing all your suggestions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This might be just showing the research you have done rather than code snippets, but we do like people to show willing before we invest the time in creating an answer. See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for more detail.

Comment: I am not aware of any option here.

Comment: if you are using ightning-tab in your account record page, can you not use a simple template:if to render/hide the tab ?

Comment: @RahulBoinepally I understood this question to be about the standard tab set component used in the page via the Lightning app builder rather than a custom component, hence my comment.